# How to obtain a user instance in django application

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, profile

I'm trying to obtain a user instance for the profile page in django app but I'm finding some difficulties implementing that functionality. I have the following blocks of code:

```
models.py

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, primary_key=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="")
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/user_profile_pics/", default="images/default_profile_pics/default.jpg")
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.lastname} profile'
```

serializers.py

```
class user_profile_serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = '__all__'
```

views.py

```
class user_profile(generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = user_profile_serializer
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        user = self.get_serializer(request.user).data
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            return Response(user, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            pass
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('profile/', user_profile.as_view(), name="user-profile"),
]
```

When ever I assess the profile url, I get an error message `'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'data'` I have tried a couple of approaches but none worked. Please, how do I obtain a specific user from the database?

Comment: What do you expect to be in `user.data` (-> `request.user.data`) in your view if the user is not logged in, ie. it's instance of `AnonymousUser`? Maybe you should check first if the user is logged in (`request.user.is_authenticated`)

Comment: I tried it but it's not working, I even encountered a NoneType error

Comment: define "not working"

Answer (score 1):

`request.user` is AnonymousUser when the user is not logged in. In that case that object does not have `data` attribute. Hence the error you get. One thing you can do is check `request.user.is_authenticated` and if the user is not authenticated, return some other value / or None. And try logging in before trying to access the `user.data` value.

Comment: Thanks @moddayjob. I updated the `views.py` in my question above. I tried to check if the user is authenticated, yet get similar error. `Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field 'firstname' on serializer 'user_profile_serializer'.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the 'AnonymousUser' instance.
Original exception text was: 'nonymousUser' object has no attribute 'firstname'.` Please is there any other part of the code I implemented wrongly? I'm already logged in as an admin

Comment: Look, in this line `user = self.get_serializer(request.user).data`, you are trying to serialize the user object. But the user still Anonymous user at this line. Because you check `if request.user.is_authenticated:` on the following line. So you get that error. Swap those lines, it will probably work. You will not get error, but you will not get a serialized user object either because you are not logged in.